# Calling UITableView scrollEnabled issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my first question about `TableView` I have a view for UITableViewController and a view for UITableViewCell. I've created a different CellView design for UITableViewController.

My cell view is working fine. I've a small issue that once I click on the `btnEdit` it won't stop the UITableViewController from scrolling. Please how can I solve this issue?

posListViewController.h

```
                                                         //UPDATED
@interface posListViewController : UITableViewController <CellHandlingDelegate> //ISSUE{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableV;

//UPDATED
-(void) buttonWasSelected:(id)sender;
```

posListViewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PosListViewCell *cell = (PosListViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PosListViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[PosListViewCell class]]){
                cell = (PosListViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    NSDictionary *selectedContent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setData:selectedContent];
    return cell;
}

//UPDATED
- (void) buttonWasSelected:(id)sender{

    self.tableV.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

PosListViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//UPDATED
@protocol CellHandlingDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) buttonWasSelected:(id)sender;
@end

@class posListViewController;

@interface posListViewCell : UITableViewCell {
        posListViewController *control;
}

//UPDATED
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<CellHandlingDelegate> parentDelegate;
```

PosListViewCell.m

```
-(void)creat {
    tapGestureRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(value1)];
    tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
}

//Every cell has it own button when it is selected and click on the selected one it will be deleted.
//while it is selected the scroll should NOT be moving. 
- (IBAction)btnEdit:(id)sender event:(id)event{

    lblEdit.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    lblEdit.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    [lblLpl addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer1];

    control.tableV.scrollEnabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"CLICKED");
}

-(void)value1 {
    //Delete that value......
}
```

Comment: can you check if control refers to the tableview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the reference to your parent view controller in each cell is not the best way to implement this.

Why don't you implement a delegate which is implemented by your posListViewController instead. And from there. You can disable the scroll. Something like this.

```
@protocol CellHandlingDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void) buttonWasSelected:(id)sender;
@end
```

Let your cell class have this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CellHandlingDelegate> parentDelegate;
```

Then in posListViewController.h add

And in posListViewController.m add handler function.

```
  - (void) buttonWasSelected:(id)sender{
     // Disable scrolling of table 
}
```

**EDIT:**
Make the following changes:

1. In posListViewController.m,  assign the delegate to self as shown below. When you run pls tell me if the delegate function is being called.

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
PosListViewCell *cell = (PosListViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PosListViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[PosListViewCell class]]){
            cell = (PosListViewCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}    

cell.parentDelagate = self; <== ADD THIS !!!

NSDictionary *selectedContent = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setData:selectedContent];
return cell;
}
```

`

1. The delegate member variable should be weak not retain else it can cause retain cycle

Comment: Excuse me, now I should create a new class and add the @protocol ?

Comment: you can define the protocol in your tableviewcell class itself.

Comment: I've put the `@protocol` & `@property` in the tableviewcell class. Shouldn't I put the last code in the tableviewcell class to? Sorry because this is new for me.

Comment: no thats the implementation of the protocol .. and needs to go in the class which registers itself as a delegate of this protocol. Its like saying.. the Cell class wants something to be done when something happens on it. it doesn't know who and what. The ViewController creates the tableview and ..  sets itself as delegate. when the cell is done it calls the delegate and the view controller's function gets called.

Comment: I've updated my code above and sorry it didn't work, it is not passing inside the method. Sorry I'm new for this method.

Comment: U will also need to set the delegate to the view controller .. Read about delegates to understand more

Comment: Thanks I'll search and I hope I can find the answer.

Comment: Hi, I've read about the delegate method and I have a problem that `CellHandlingDelegate`  Cannot find protocol declaration for `CellHandlingDelegate`. And I searched a lot about that and I should managed the `#import` but it didn't works. Please I need your help.

Comment: Can you update your code? where did you define the delegate.. ? where did you declare it.. how you are using it.. lets take it one step at a time.. first get it to compile and then get it to work

Comment: I have updated my code but I can't run the code while I've the `Cannot find protocol declaration for CellHandlingDelegate` issue.

Comment: I have added the missing code take a look. Also i hope you have a plan to enable scrolling at the appropriate time.

Comment: Hello, sorry I was out for some reasons. I've tried the code but unfortunately there is two issues. I couldn't add the delegate member as a weak because I'm not using ARC. Second issue is I am getting alert ` "assigning to 'id<CellHandelingDelegate>' from incompatible type 'posListViewController.m'" `

Comment: Did you make you post list vc a delegate for the protocol in the header file.

Comment: No I couldn't and I get this issue when I try to delegate `Cannot find protocol declaration for CellHandlingDelegate` while I've written the header file.

Comment: U need to include the header file